# How to do list comprehension that display a list elements whose elements and index are divisible by 6?

Tags: python

How to do list comprehension that display a list elements whose elements and index are divisible by 6?

Here is my list  :

```
lst = [6,12,8,9,1,18,24]
```

Comment: Sounds like a fun homework problem. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> lst = [6,12,8,9,1,18,24]
>>> print([value for index,value in enumerate(lst) if index%6==0 and value%6==0])
[6 , 24]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [6,12,8,9,1,18,24]

result = list(filter(lambda x: (x % 6 == 0), lst))

print(result) #[6, 12, 18, 24]
```